# Unexpected resource reference type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I was working on a project of mine and had just asked android studio to update it from gradle version 2.3.3 to 3.0.1.
I looked up a couple of sites including this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html

However, as instructed on the above link, I modified my themes.xml file from

```
<item name="attr/color_text_primary">@color/white</item>
```

to

```
<item type="attr" name="color_text_primary">@color/white</item>
```

However, now android studio is showing an error at *@color/white* as:

*Unexpected resource type; expected value of type @attr/*

I am not sure what is the error. I have followed what is written in the above link. Can someone please help. TIA

My attrs.xml has:

```
<attr name="color_text_primary" format="reference|color" />
```

My colors.xml:

```
<color name="white">#ffffffff</color>
```

Comment: Please don't add useless keywords to your question title, the tags at the bottom are enough to indicate the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. You are saying that item is "attr", but it's "color".
Should be:

```
<item type="color" name="color_text_primary">@color/white</item>
```